# What is the equivalent for this Persian expression "The cat can't reach the meat, says it smells bad"

Tags: expressions

The expression, which implies the meat is placed on a counter too high for the cat to reach, is used when someone who can't achieve a position which is notoriously high or expensive, would pretend they don't like it.
"Gorbeh dastesh be goosht nemireseh migeh boo mideh"
Example: I don't like Ferraris, seats are too low. (said by someone owning a Fiat 500)
Or: I don't like to own that $20M house up the hill, it's a long drive to get there.(said by a non millionnaire).

---

Thanks for the answer... "The fox can't reach the grapes, says they are sour." is an acceptable equivalent. Although in Persian it's used as an expression and a proverb exactly as mentioned above while the sentence with the fox is actually never used as is, but rather "sour grapes" as a reference to the fable.
This is not a duplicate of the Jealousy question IMO. They are not jealous, maybe hypocrite. A duplicate is when the same question is asked. You can't consider any question related to jealousy as duplicate! I wanted to know the equivalent to that specific proverb and I got it. I hope the admin will not bury this inside a mass of jealousy related questions so that it helps others.

Comment: @KannE The OP didn't mention jealousy, but the exact situation that 'sour grapes' describes.

Comment: @KannE Are you seriously saying that "someone who can't achieve a position which is notoriously high ... would pretend they don't like it" doesn't involve jealousy? And this definition of sour grapes seems to have been overlooked: << _sour grapes_
a situation where someone criticizes another person or accuses them of using unfair methods because they are jealous of their success >>
[[Easy Learning Idioms Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sour-grapes)]

Comment: Again, OP's example: 'I [wouldn't] like to own that $20M house up the hill; it's a long drive to get there.(said by a non millionnaire).' Not jealous!? ... And you'd lose your bet. I've just had another look to make sure, and I distinctly remember the answer 'catty' as well as the previous 'sour grapes'.

Comment: You are jealous of something if you have it & want to keep it but fear losing it. If you fear that a rival might steal it, you are jealous of them, too. If someone has something, and you wish you had the like, you *envy* them. Ass @KannE says, you can have "sour grapes" if you wish you had something but regretfully know you can't get one, and you try to rationalise your regret by arguing *against* having one, even if you have no envy or other ill-feeling against anyone who has one. Who wants the bother of a country estate? A country estate is something I'd hate!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**sour grapes**

> From Aesop's fable The Fox and the Grapes, in which a fox, unable to
>   reach grapes it is seeking, convinces itself that they must have been
>   unripe (therefore, sour) all along and so not worthwhile trying for in
>   the first place.

Example sentence:

> I think his comments about that new car are just **sour grapes** because
>   he can't afford it.

(From [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sour_grapes), both quotes.)

---

[The Fox & the Grapes - Library of Congress Aesop Fables](http://www.read.gov/aesop/005.html) (read.gov/aesop)

> There are many who pretend to despise and belittle that which is beyond their reach.

---

[The meaning and origin of the expression: Sour grapes](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sour-grapes.html) (phrases.org.uk)

> In the fable The Fox and the Grapes, which is attributed to the
>   ancient Greek writer Aesop, the fox isn't able to reach the grapes and
>   declares them to be sour...

---

Comment: Yep, this is what I instantly thought of.